# Get a single class name as a string from an element

Tags: javascript, string

This is probably simple but I am having some difficulty. I am trying to return a specific class name from an element as a string. There will be many interactive_items with different class name that follow the `element__content__item` pattern so I need the `element__content__item` class name.

Right now I am just trying the first element found.

I need to get the string `slider__content__item`

```
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.interactive__item')]
const regex = new RegExp(/^.*(content__item).*$/g)

const result = elements[0].className.match(regex).toString()
```

This returns `slider__content__item interactive__item entry` which is correct but then how do I pull out the slider__content__item class as a string.

If there is a better way to do this I am all ears.

```
<aside class="slider__content__item interactive__item entry">

</aside>
```

Comment: [.classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\w+__content__item/g`

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.interactive__item')]
const regex = new RegExp(/\w+__content__item/g)

const result = elements[0].className.match(regex).toString()
console.log(result)
```

```html
<aside class="slider__content__item interactive__item entry">

</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.interactive__item'));
const regex = new RegExp(/^.*(content__item).*$/g)

const result = Array.from(elements[0].classList); // you have all item classes after that write your mathing statements
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer will solve the issue, that will add more value rather than code only answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with `document.getElementById(id of the element).className`
or `document.getElementByTagName(name of the tag).className` ?